# Unexpected behaviour of python matrix (list of lists), assignment is changing whole column

Tags: python, arrays

please help me with a question, cause Im getting mad.
I'm creating a 0-matrix, than tried to changed it's first element value to one, but it changes the whole column instead, and I don't get why:

```
    def id_mtrx(n):
        m = [[0]*n]*n
        m[0][0]=1
        return m
```

here is output:

```
    [[1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

```
while I was expecting:
```

```
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

```
It looks very simple, what can be wrong?
```

Comment: Hello, this is a classic problem (though I'm unable right now to find posts about the same problem): your matrix is created by doubling [0, 0], which actually creates 2 references to the SAME mutable (can be modified in-place) object. So when you modify it to [1, 0], both references now point to that.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple references to the same list object instead of creating new list, try:

```
n = 2
m = [[0 for _ in range(0, n)] for _ in range (0, n)]
m[0][0] = 1
print(m)
```

output is:
`[[1, 0], [0, 0]]`